# How to pass shared pointer to a class through another class?

Tags: c++

I have a class `A`  that holds a vector of shared pointers

```
class A
{
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<object>> vec;
A(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<object>> vec_) : vec(vec_) {}
};
```

and a class `B` that contains many `A`

```
class B
{
std::vector<A> manyA;

//What should the constructor look like?
};
```

The class `B` needs to take the shared_ptrs as input to its constructor and then initialize all its `A` objects and distribute the shared-ptrs to them.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: It sounds like you already have a pretty good idea of at least what you want the *type* of the constructor to be. What argument(s) should it take to satisfy the conditions you just set forth? That's a good place to start.

Comment: We're going to need more information here. What do you mean distribute? If you have 10K pointers in an array, do you want 10 A objects with 1000 elements each, or 1000 A objects with 10 each? Why can't B just take a vector of A as its parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend storing shared_ptr in your vector:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> manyA;
B(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> v) : manyA(v){ }
```

`vector` will copy the `shared_ptr` meaning the reference count will increase by 1.

If you don't want to use shared_ptr make sure you store copy of A in your vector.